# RSpec: Troubleshooting failing test that works for some devs and not others

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails, capybara-webkit

Hoping someone can walk me through troubleshooting a failing spec that is passing in CI and on my desktop machine but failing on my laptop (MacBook).

This is the failure:

```
$ rspec spec/features/media_files_spec.rb

Randomized with seed 39713
WARNING: The next major version of capybara-webkit will require at least version 5.0 of Qt. You're using version 4.8.7.
....F

Failures:

  1) MediaFiles upload additional file to section
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_css(".photoset .photo", count: 2)
       expected to find css ".photoset .photo" 2 times, found 1 match: ""
     # ./spec/features/media_files_spec.rb:43:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/support/background_jobs.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/support/background_jobs.rb:5:in `run_background_jobs_immediately'
     # ./spec/support/background_jobs.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 12 seconds (files took 3.03 seconds to load)
5 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/media_files_spec.rb:24 # MediaFiles upload additional file to section
```

I'm going to be traveling next week so want to get this laptop stabilized but not sure why this is failing locally while passing elsewhere? Not sure where to begin. Thoughts?

Comment: Are you getting the same error about your version of `Qt` on your desktop machine (in which case it's unrelated)? It may be some sort of weird difference in that dependency and is something that is system-dependent as opposed to something that is kept the same by your Gemfile/bundler.

Comment: Ya. curious, but same Qt5 error on both machines (deprecation warning)

Comment: Sometimes these sort of things are related to the load order of required files.  Load order is file-system dependent unless you explicitly order it.(e.g. linux/osx are different)  You might try to sort any required files.  `Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].sort.each { |f| require f }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my own answer because maybe this can help others.

Turns out this was an issue with my `.env` on the failing machine. Some ENV variables were not in sync.

Tough nuts!